# transform one data format to another with created additional variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Say , i have such dataset.

```
mydat=structure(list(Date = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("2019-09-23 07-AM", 
"2019-09-23 08-AM", "2019-09-23 09-AM"), class = "factor"), Symbol = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "BTCUSD", class = "factor"), Open = c(8065.1, 
8127.07, 8082.32), High = c(8085.04, 8137.61, 8135.93), Low = c(8065.09, 
8058.95, 8022.19), Close = c(8085.04, 8065.1, 8127.07), Volume = c(14.286264, 
22.74164, 42.751659)), .Names = c("Date", "Symbol", "Open", "High", 
"Low", "Close", "Volume"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

the Date var must be timestamp, i.e. tranformed data

```
Timestamp,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume_(BTC),Volume_(Currency),Weighted_Price
1325317920,4.39,4.39,4.39,4.39,0.45558087,2.0000000193,4.39
1325317980,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
1325318040,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
1325318100,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
1325318160,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
1325318220,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
```

here must be addtional variable - `Weighted_Price`
to calculate it i should use simple formula `[(Hgh + Low + Close) / 3]` manually

How to get desired format in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow your description, you want to convert `Date` to timestamp and calculate mean of 3 values. Using base R, that would be

```
transform(mydat, timestamp = as.integer(as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %I-%p", 
          tz = "UTC")), weighted_avg = (High + Low + Close)/3)
```

Using `dplyr` and `lubridate`, we can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

mydat %>%
  mutate(timestamp = as.integer(ymd_h(Date)), 
         weighted_avg = (High + Low + Close) / 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `anytime` from `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
library(dplyr)
mydat %>%
   mutate(timestamp - as.integer(anytime(Date)),
              weighted_avg = rowMeans(.[c('High', "Low", "Close")]))
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
transform(mydat, timestamp = as.integer(strptime(Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d  %I-%p", tz = "UTC")), weighted_avg = rowMeans(mydat[c("High", "Low", "Close")]))
```